# Laravel redirect to another route from route file

Tags: laravel-5, routes

I have the following routes in my web.php route file:

```
Route::get('/contacts', 'ContactController@getAll')->name('getContacts');
Route::get('/contactsData', 'ContactController@getData')->name('getContactData');
```

And now I want to redirect to the above route name with the following condition:

```
$host = request()->getHttpHost();
if($host=="example.com")
{  
    return redirect()->route('getContacts');
}
```

But I got the following errors:

```
Route [getContacts] not defined.
```

I have tried the following as well:

```
if($host=="example.com")
{  
   return redirect()->action('ContactController@getAll');
}
```

Got the following error:

```
Class ContactController not defined.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the current URL on the view and then redirect.
For example:

```
@if(Request::url() === 'http://example.com')
    <script>window.location = "http://example.com/contacts";</script>
@endif
```